# Qt static compile cannot read path

Tags: c++, qt, static

i use Qt5.6.0 msvc , and vs 2013, and install python-2.7.12 also, when I compile Qt to build static, i get this error, 
Note: driver E not the main drive

```
    Cannot read E:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtbase/mkspecs   /win32-msvc20
13 /qmake.conf: The system cannot find the path specified.
Could not read qmake configuration file E:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0
/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013 /qmake.conf.
Error processing project file: E:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0\qt.pro
Qmake failed, return code 3
```

this is the what i used in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013

```
- set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013  
- set QTDIR=E:\Qt\QT-EVE~1.0\qtbase  
- set PATH=E:\Qt\QT-EVE~1.0\qtbase\bin;%PATH%  
- set PYTHONPATH=%E:\Python27%;E:\Python27\Lib 

- cd E:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0 
- configure -static -platform win32-msvc2013  -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp
```

Answer (score 0):

ok problem solved, Just add in Environment Variables shorted path for Qt

```
E:\Qt\QT-EVE~1.0\qtbase\bin;%PATH%;E:\Python27;E:\Python27\Lib
```